# Mix of regex and non-regex in bash if-statement

Tags: regex, bash, macos, if-statement, command-line

Inside of my `$foo` variable I have this data (please pay close attention to the `.`s and `,`s):

```
,example.com,de.wikipedia.org,reddit,stackoverflow.com.,amazon.,
```

I am trying to write an `if` statement in `bash` that basically works like this:

```
if [[ "${foo}" =~ *','[a-z0-9]','* || "${foo}" =~ *','[a-z0-9]'.,'* ]]; then
    echo "Invalid input detected"
else
    echo "OK"
fi
```

It would echo `Invalid input detected` since `reddit` and `amazon.` are in `$foo`.

If I change the contents of `$foo` to be:

```
,example.com,de.wikipedia.org,www.reddit.com,stackoverflow.com.,amazon.com,
```

Then it would echo `OK`.

I am using bash 3.2.57(1)-release on OS X 10.11.6 El Capitan.

Comment: Assuming you will be splitting on the commas later on anyway, why not do that first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
if [[ $foo =~ ,[a-z0-9]*, || $foo =~ ,[a-z0-9]*\., ]]; then
    echo "Invalid input detected"
else
    echo "OK"
fi
```

Notes:

1. `=~` is a regular expression operator.  The right-hand-side needs to be a regular expression, not a glob.
2. `,` is not a shell-active character.  Thus, it does not need any special quoting.
3. `[a-z0-9]` matches exactly one alphanumeric.  Since we want to allow for more any number, use `[a-z0-9]*`
4. In regular expressions, `','*` matches zero or more commas.  This is not what you want.  One might write `,.*` which, because, `.` is a wildcard, matches a comma followed by zero or more of anything.  Since the regex is not anchored to the end, adding a final `.*` makes no difference.
5. Inside of `[[...]]` there is no word splitting.  So shell variables do not the double-quoting that need elsewhere.
6. Note that, in `[a-z0-9]`, the exact characters that match `a-z` or `0-9` depend on the collation order in the locale.

Comment: Just noticed, how come the second if statement isn't `$foo =~ ,[a-z0-9]*\.,`? Is this what you mean by "adding a final `.*` makes no difference."? I visually interpret that if statement as matching only one alphanumeric and not (possibly) several.

Comment: @leetbacoon Oops, you're right.   That was a typo.  Answer updated.